# How can i create a view that is bigger than the screen in Windows8

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to create an app for Windows 8 with a real big grid.
The user should be able to scroll over this grid in the horizontal direction.

But even if i define the width od the Screen to a number that is bigger than the Resolution widt, the grid appears just in the middle of the Screen.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I colored the border of the main-grid in Aqua so i can see it better

Also I colored the backround of the dynamic grid in blue.

This is the XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>

    <!-- Auflistung von Elementen, die von dieser Seite angezeigt werden -->
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="itemsViewSource"
        Source="{Binding Items}"/>

    <!-- TODO: Diese Zeile löschen, wenn der Schlüssel "AppName" in "App.xaml" deklariert ist -->
    <x:String x:Key="AppName">My Application</x:String>
</Page.Resources>

<!--
    Dieses Raster fungiert als Stammbereich für die Seite, die zwei Zeilen definiert:
    * Zeile 0 enthält die Schaltfläche "Zurück" und den Seitentitel.
    * Zeile 1 enthält den Rest des Seitenlayouts.
-->
<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Schaltfläche "Zurück" und Seitentitel -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Grid.Column="1" Text="{StaticResource AppName}" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="705,92,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    </Grid>

    <!-- Raster mit horizontalem Bildlauf (wird in den meisten Ansichtsstatus verwendet) -->
    <GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        TabIndex="1"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Margin="0,-4,0,0"
        Padding="116,0,116,46" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" SelectionMode="None" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Aqua"/>
```

And ths is the C#:

```
this.InitializeComponent();

this.itemGridView.FlowDirection = Windows.UI.Xaml.FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
this.itemGridView.ItemContainerStyle = null;

pageTitle.Text = startFolder.name;
Windows.UI.Xaml.Thickness th = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
this.Margin = th;

this.itemGridView.Margin = th;
this.itemGridView.Width = 2000;
```

Comment: If I understand your question, you need to wrap your scrollable content in a <ScrollViewer>.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but this is not what i meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bart, I had the same issue while developing the landing grid page for my app. Don't use the Grid.Column is the XAML as you have not defined any ColumnDefinitions in the main grid. Don't be confused with the grid that has columndefinition, as it's used only for the Page Title and Back Button.

Your Grid view XAML should look something like this.

```
<!-- Horizontal scrolling grid used in most view states -->
    <GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
        TabIndex="1"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Padding="116,136,116,46"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultGridItemTemplate}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"/>
```

In the C# code, just have the following line and remove everything

```
this.InitializeComponent();
```

Answer (score 0):

The GridView will grow as you add more content to it - you haven't shown us what it's bound to and hence how it's displaying the boxes already in there.

If your itemsViewSource contains more items then they should appear in the GridView and it will scroll to show them all.